# Fragment Activity onCreate get called again on Back press

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one fragment activity and multiple fragments get replaced .when i called new activity from fragment then it is called oncreate method of fragment activity while on back press of new activity called.it goes to root fragment instead of current fragment.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Temp.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please be more clear what the problem is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: When i am calling new activity from fragment and go back then fragment activity is starting from scratch instead of current state.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your fragment:

```
public YourFragment()
{
    this.retainInstance = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start new activity from fragment by using following code.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), Temp.class);
startActivity(intent);
```